# Problem with \pause when using a macro with \includegraphics

Tags: beamer, macros, includegraphics, pause

I defined the following command that allows me to put icons in math mode:

```
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{%
\mathord{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{#1}}}%
}
```

The problem is that if I want to use it in beamer as in the following MWE, the icon doesn't get shaded correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\newcommand{\icon}[1]{%
\mathord{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item x
        \pause
        \item $\icon{file.png}$
        \pause
        \item x
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I modify the `icon` command so as to "propagate" correctly the shading information in a reusable way?

Comment: Why math mode to use it?

Comment: Because I usually use this command within formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this trick by @Ulrike Fischer](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/769#issuecomment-1130279493) :

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}


\usepackage{transparent}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@startcovered{%
  \beamer@smuggle{%
  \global\advance\beamer@coveringdepth by 1\relax%
  \beamer@actions{\pgfsys@begininvisible\aftergroup\beamer@@spacingcover}{%
     \pgfsys@endinvisible\aftergroup\beamer@@spacingcover%
     }%
  \def\opaqueness<##1>##2{%
    \only<##1>{%
      \beamer@actions{%
    \transparent{\fpeval{##2/100}}%
      }%
      {% end code needed???
      }}}%
  \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe<\beamer@minimum %ok, at beginning
    \begingroup
      \beamer@saveanother
      \advance\beamer@minimum by-\beamer@slideinframe
      \beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@minimum
      \beamer@uncoverbeforeactions
      \beamer@restoreanother
    \endgroup
  \else
    \begingroup
      \beamer@saveanother
      \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-\beamer@minimum
      \beamer@uncoverafteractions
      \beamer@restoreanother
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \beamer@do
  }%
}

\makeatother



\newcommand{\icon}[1]{%
\text{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item x
        \pause
        \item $\icon{example-image-duck}$
        \pause
        \item x
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]